# AsynchronousServerSocketChannel not closing the established connections

Tags: java, nio

Have a listener implemented using AsynchronousServerSocketChannel. I open the channnel , bind to the port and start accepting connections. i am able to listen and read the messages. The problem event after closing the channel my listener still accepting data.

I close the server channel socket connection as below.

```
 this.serverChannel.close();
 this.serverChannel = null;
```

Here is the completion handler to accept connections

```
 this.serverChannel
                .accept(null,
                        new java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Void>() {

                            @Override
                            public void completed(
                                    AsynchronousSocketChannel result,
                                    Void attachment) {
                                acceptConnections();
                                read(new HSLParsingContext(), result);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {
                                if (!(exc instanceof AsynchronousCloseException)) 

                        });

public void read(final HSLParsingContext context,
            final AsynchronousSocketChannel channel) {

        try {

            channel.read(context.buffer, null,
                    new java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler<Integer, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        public void completed(Integer bytesRead, Void attachment) {
                            try {
                                HSLSysLogTcpListener.this.logger.infoFmt(
                                        "Bytes received: %s ", bytesRead);
                                if (bytesRead > 0) {
                                    messageHandler(context, false);
                                }

                                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                                    // when nothing is there to read in the
                                    // channel make sure there
                                    // is nothing in the content buffer before
                                    // closing the channel
                                    if (context.content.length() > 0) {
                                        messageHandler(context, true);
                                    }
                                    throw new EOFException();
                                }

                                // keep reading data asynchronously
                                read(context, channel);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                failed(e, null);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failed(Throwable e, Void attachment) {
                            logReadFailureAndClose(channel, e);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logReadFailureAndClose(channel, e);
        }
```

I kind of feel that the AsynchronousSocketChannel than opened by the accept method is not closed. Hence i am receving the messages event after closing the AsynchronousServerSocketChannel .

Is there as way to close AsynchronousSocketChannel  while closing the serversocketchannel.Please let me know the best was fully stop the AsynchronousServerSocketChannel and it asscoiated AsynchronousSocketChannel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> AsynchronousServerSocketChannel not closing the established connections

I agree. It doesn't. It isn't meant to do that. There's no reason why closing the server socket channel should close anything else.

If you want *accepted sockets* to be closed, you have to close them yourself, and you aren't. The close happens, or should happen, in `logReadFailureAndClose()`, which you haven't posted. Closing the server socket channel has nothing to do with it. If you want to close everything at the same time you will need an up-to-date list of accepted sockets, and close them all when you close the server socket channel.

Comment: i do close in logReadFailureAndClose(). This happen will i bytesRead == -1 (end of the stream) is reached or some time i get connection reset by peer and it forces the socket chanel to be closed . But there are times , when neither of this event occurs and the uses want to cancel the listener .  At that time i just close AsynchronousServerSocketChannel .  How can i get the list of AsynchronousSocketChannel  that are not yet closed . Is this a unique id kind of attribute for each AsynchronousSocketChannel  ??

Comment: Also I read about adding AsynchronousChannelGroup to AsynchronousServerSocketChannel  and calling shutdown on the group. Will that work?

Comment: @KarthikeyanRamasamy No, that's just a thread factory really. You have to do what I said in my answer: keep a collection of accepted sockets and close them all yourself.